# When we use user defined functions in SQL to return a table, why don't we use begin and end?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

When we use user defined functions in SQL  to return a table, why don't we use `BEGIN`and `END`?

e.g.

```
CREATE FUNCTION Customers
(@minId int)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN(SELECT *
    FROM   TrackingItem ti
    WHERE  ti.Id >= @minId)
```

works

but

```
CREATE FUNCTION Customers
(@minId int)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
BEGIN
   RETURN(SELECT *
   FROM   TrackingItem ti
   WHERE  ti.Id >= @minId)
END
```

doesn't work

Comment: Tag the dbms product used. (That code doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all.)

Comment: As you are new here (Welcome!), please allow me one hint: It would be very kind to tick the acceptance check below the (best) answer's vote counter. This will 1) mark this issue as solved 2) make it easier for followers to find the best solution 3) pay points to the answerer and 4) pay points to you. Once you've crossed the 15 points border yourself you are asked to vote on contributions. This is the SO-way to say thank you. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

You did not tag the DBMS, but from your syntax I guess this is SQL Server...

### Good approach: inline TVF

The **inline** syntax (without the `BEGIN...END`) works like a `VIEW` with parameters. On usage it will be fully inlined by the query optimizer - just as if the code was written in the place where the function is used (almost). This means: Full usage of indexes, statistics, chached results...

But - which is not possible in all cases (but in most cases) - you must be able to write your full logic in one single statement.

### Bad approach: multi-statement TVF

The second example needs a table definition which fits to the result you want to return. Your code has to use an `INSERT` against this virtual table and then return it. This is missing in your example.

This approach is absolutely to be avoided if ever possible. The query optimizer will not be able to *look into this code* in order to predict the result. It will not be able to use interimistic / cached results or indexes / statistics in the way an inlined query would do it.

Answer (score 0):

The first one, **without** the BEGIN and END is called an "Inline Table Valued Function". You can only have the single statement inside the function body to immediately return the resultset.

The second one **with** the BEGIN and END is called a "Multi Statement Table Valued Function". You can have multiple statements inside the function body and then at the bottom have a RETURN statement to return the resultset. This allows you to e.g. populate a TABLE variable and then return it.

An Inline Table Valued Function can be thought of like a view - in it gets expanded out into the calling query, statistics on the underlying tables can be used to give a better execution plan.

Multi Statement Valued Functions do not expand out like this, and don't benefit from the same benefits when an execution plan is created.

So, it's best practise to avoid multi statement table valued functions, and prefer inline instead, in order to reap these benefits and avoid potential performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can use in this ways, you are returning table type information and you have to define table with columns and return data through the table: Try following suppose you have 2 columns id and name:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Customers(@minId INT)
RETURNS @@table TABLE (id INT, NAME VARCHAR(20)) 
AS
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO @@table
   SELECT id, name
   FROM TrackingItem ti
   WHERE ti.Id >= @minId

   RETURN
END
```